# Django south: access model's __unicode__() method

Tags: python, django, django-south

In django south data migration file, how can I access model's `__unicode__()` method?

Here is a simple example:

I have a Person class in models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I then create a data migration with
`python manage.py datamigration myapp check_person`

In the data migration file, I have

```
class Migration(DataMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        "Write your forwards methods here."
        for person in orm.Person.objects.all():
            print person
```

Instead of printing the person's name, it prints

```
Person object
Person object
...
```

when I do:

```
from myapp.models import Person

class Migration(DataMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        "Write your forwards methods here."
        print hasattr(orm.Person, '__unicode__')
        print hasattr(Person, '__unicode__')
```

It prints

```
False
True
```

My question is that are those expected? Why can't south orm access `__unicode__()` method? How can I access it?

**Edit:**
Doing `from myapp.models import Person` and access Person objects directly by `Person.objects.all()` does not work for me, because the Person model will be removed from models.py in the next migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `orm.Person.objects.all()`, you might want to import the original `Person` model and query on that instead. `orm.Person` is not the same thing as `Person`, it sort of depends on the big data structure `models` that defined at the end of each migration file to figure out the model information.

However, `orm.Model` would still work if your original model has been changed, that's why south could work with models that have changes, the `model` variable takes a snapshot of the models.py at the time it is created.

[South doc explains this in details](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ormfreezing.html).

> South doesn’t freeze every aspect of a model; for example, it doesn’t
>   preserve new managers, or custom model methods, as these would require
>   serialising the python code that runs those method (and the code that
>   depends on, and so forth).

#### Edit:

Sounds like OP would like to use the model `__unicode__` property for certain purposes but the model would be deleted right after. Since an import error would occur in this case, I wouldn't bother using `__unicode__` anymore, instead I would suggest handling this by manually accessing model fields using `orm.Model`(since `__unicode__` is composed by field values anyway).

Comment: Thank you! I end up using 'from myapp.models import Person' and it works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry but I have to undo accepting the answer. Importing directly from django models will cause import error in future if those models are deleted from models.py

Comment: But it doesn't make my answer invalid, you would have to do `try except`exception handling in your manual migration around the import statement so that when the model is there you import it, otherwise the migration is skipped.

Comment: You answered the 'why' part of my question perfectly, but it does not answer the 'how' part. I need the data migration to copy data from a to-be-deleted model to a new model. In the consecutive migration, I will delete the to-be-deleted model. So at the point of applying the data migration, the to-be-deleted model still exists in the orm, but not models.py anymore. That's why try-except will not work. It will always go to the except block.

Comment: You didn't say your model would be delete in your original post, in that case of course it would never work, because you are depending on non-field properties in your model for the migration. My last comment is valid in the case when you would delete your model several migrations later not right on that migration, in that case I wouldn't recommend using `__unicode__` at all, you need to handle the special case using model field.

Comment: You are right. I didn't realize that it was relevant to provide the information that the model would soon be deleted. I will modify my question. If you would like to modify your answer accordingly, I'd be happy to accept it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sure thing, I edited the answer. Sorry but I don't think I could come up with anything better than this, hope it helps a little.